# Count a row's appearance in foreign keys on another table as a generated column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables, *buildings* and *reports*. a row in *reports* has one relationship to a row in *buildings* but *buildings* can have many reports.

I have aa query that returns a table of building id as well as how many reports are related to it:

```
SELECT
 buildings.bin, A.report_count
 FROM
 buildings JOIN ( 
  SELECT fk_bin, COUNT(fk_bin) 
  AS report_count FROM fisp_filings
  GROUP BY fk_bin) A ON buildings.bin = A.fk_bin
```

Result:

```
___________________
|bin |report_count|
-------------------
|1001|           3|
-------------------
```

I would like to have this column showing me the report count within my *buildings* table.

Something like this: ( doesn't work )

```
ALTER TABLE buildings ADD report_count int not null GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( fk_bin, COUNT(fk_bin) AS report_count FROM fisp_filings GROUP BY fk_bin ) A ON buildings.bin = A.fk_bin ) STORED;
```

Is it possible to have this count on my table without creating a view?

Comment: _"Is it possible to have this count on my table without creating a view?"_ you can create a column and then create a rule on UPDATE and INSERT into fisp_filings to update that column..

Comment: There are ways to do that, all of which are somewhat unsavory and bad for performance. Why do you want that, and what is wrong with the proper solution of using a view?